# React Native: Native module RNI18nModule tried to override reactnativei18n - no duplicates

Tags: react-native

I'm currently trying to run a React-Native build on Android. Receiving the error message below. All the resources online state that, if you receive this error, there is a duplicate in the `MainApplication.java`. I can however not find any duplicates in my `MainApplication.java`. I've tried to remove the build folder and rebuild but this doesn't seem to work.

[image]

What else could cause this error?

MainApplication.java

```
package com.PROJECT;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import fr.bamlab.rnimageresizer.ImageResizerPackage;
import fr.snapp.imagebase64.RNImgToBase64Package;
import com.imagepicker.ImagePickerPackage;
import com.lugg.ReactNativeConfig.ReactNativeConfigPackage;
import com.idehub.GoogleAnalyticsBridge.GoogleAnalyticsBridgePackage;
import com.dylanvann.fastimage.FastImageViewPackage;
import io.sentry.RNSentryPackage;
import com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.ReactNativePushNotificationPackage;
import com.i18n.reactnativei18n.ReactNativeI18n;
import com.AlexanderZaytsev.RNI18n.RNI18nPackage;
import com.learnium.RNDeviceInfo.RNDeviceInfo;
import com.zoontek.rndevmenu.RNDevMenuPackage;
import com.rt2zz.reactnativecontacts.ReactNativeContacts;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

      @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new ImageResizerPackage(),
            new RNImgToBase64Package(),
            new ImagePickerPackage(),
            new ReactNativeConfigPackage(),
            new GoogleAnalyticsBridgePackage(),
            new FastImageViewPackage(),
            new RNSentryPackage(),
            new ReactNativePushNotificationPackage(),
            new ReactNativeI18n(),
            new RNI18nPackage(),
            new RNDeviceInfo(),
            new RNDevMenuPackage(),
            new ReactNativeContacts()
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to add `react-native-i18n` module twice, one as an old version dependency and another as the latest version dependency.

```
import com.i18n.reactnativei18n.ReactNativeI18n;
import com.AlexanderZaytsev.RNI18n.RNI18nPackage;
```

As the latest V2 namespace has changed to `import com.AlexanderZaytsev.RNI18n.RNI18nPackage;`, remove `import com.i18n.reactnativei18n.ReactNativeI18n;` in the headers and `new ReactNativeI18n()` in `getPackages()`

Comment: Thank you for your response! After removing `remove import com.i18n.reactnativei18n.ReactNativeI18n;` and `new ReactNativeI18n()` the i18n seems to break. Afterwards it doesn't show any text in the application...

Comment: As mentioned in the docs, make you're using the release version > 2.0 and Android Build Tools `27.0.3`

Answer (score 1):

Remove ***import com.i18n.reactnativei18n.ReactNativeI18n*** and ***new ReactNativeI18n()***. It's basically the same as ***AlexanderZaytsev.RNI18n***, the developer just changed the namespace with [version 2.0](https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n/issues/95).